# Azure DevOps integration with AAD failing

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to connect an existing MS-based DevOps organisation to our AAD (O365). I have a user account nnn@outlook.com in DevOps that is both Organization Owner and a Collection Administrator.

The same outlook.com account is a Member of the target Tenant directory. I can login to portal.azure.com using that account and see all the details of the AAD. I have made the account a Global Administrator.

When I click Connect Directory, I get a list of the tenants that account has access to. My target is there and I have confirmed that the Tenant ID matches.

When trying to connect I get the error message:
"User: nnnn@outlook.com is not allowed to link organization: xxxx to AAD tenant: zzzzz. Only active members of the AAD tenant are allowed to perform the link."

I tried creating a clean guest account, PS'd it to become a Member, but get the same result.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue and have done all the pre-reqs so will be keen to find out what the issue is. Only hope I have is the comment when you PS'd a Guest to a Member that it can take days to actually work properly :-(

Comment: So the bad news is that the original account that I was using had been created for a very long time so it isn't a matter of AAD catching up. The better news is that I have placed a support request with MS so hoping to get a resolution over the next few days.

Comment: Well not sure what my issue was as they can't seem to explain it clearly but last night they made the change for me and appears to have worked so they should be able to sort you out too. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. Just finished testing and they have fixed me up as well. I asked if he could explain it but no luck. Maybe just some elevated privileges that they have. Either way, looks like the fix is for MS to take care of it.